# "No such file or directory"

Tags: python

[image: error]

Hi,
I have a library called `BioPython` for Bioinformatics with several files.
I am unable to retrieve the file and it gives me the above errors.
My Python 3.8.2 IDE shell is in documents and my BioInformatics Library file is in documents as well. I think there is something wrong with the pathway of my package for python3.8 but I am not sure. Can someone guide me towards the right direction?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/. How did you install the package? Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: Hi Pratik, welcome to Stack Overflow! @AMC is asking for some important clarifications that will help you get to a solution faster.

Comment: whatever `ls_orchis.gbk` is, the library isnt able to find it. If you are giving that as an argument, try giving the full path where that fie is located.

Comment: The path of your script is ```/Users/pratikghimire/Documents/k.py```. Please note that the name of your script is not recommended as it is too short and unclear in its meaning. Please also consider adding more of source code of ```k.py``` to help the community understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping python shell and the file you want to access in the same directory does not matter. The only thing that matters is that your working working directory must have the file in order to import it without specifying the complete path.
Well, the error clearly shows that the name of the file has been either changed or it might have been moved to some other directory. It is better to specify the full path.